# I am trying to load a Js Dynamic Audio Synth

Tags: jquery

I saw a working Javascript Piano which I would like to implement on my page as a shortcode. I have already enqueued the Js file, and I can see it when I view my page source.

This is how I enquued it:

```
function chicken_wings_scripts() {

         wp_enqueue_script( 'audiosynth',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/audiosynth.js', array(), null, true );
    }
}
```

My main challenge is I don't know how to call the code to display on frontend as the documentation is not a beginner friendly.

The documentation said "audiosynth implements a singleton class, AudioSynth"

```
Synth instanceof AudioSynth; // true

var testInstance = new AudioSynth;
testInstance instanceof AudioSynth; // true

testInstance === Synth; // true
```

This is a working example of the Piano https://keithwhor.com/music/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your enqueue is missing the action.
Try this instead :

```
/**
 * Enqueue audiosynth.
 */
function chicken_wings_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'audiosynth', get_theme_file_uri( '/js/audiosynth.js' ), array(), filemtime( get_theme_file_path( '/js/audiosynth.js' ) ), true );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'chicken_wings_scripts' );
```

**-----EDIT FULL WORKING ANSWER-----**
Do exactly the same steps.
Lets say that your theme name is **mytheme**.
Inside **mytheme** folder, you should find a `js` **folder**, if there is no one Create a `js` **folder**.
Inside the `js` **folder** or **mytheme**, add 3 **empty** files :
1- `audiosynth.js`
2- `audiosynth.view.js`
3- `audiosynth.view.fire.js`
Inside the first file `audiosynth.js`, copy and paste the content of the downloaded `audiosynth.js` file.
Inside the second file `audiosynth.view.js`, copy and paste the content of [this file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m5nicGtL8RXN59Y_YtbJG_jedPpOcqTJ/view?usp=sharing).
Inside the third file `audiosynth.view.fire.js`, **ADD ONLY** the following code :

```
var a = new AudioSynthView();
a.draw();
```

Now, open the `functions.php` of **mytheme** and add the following code :

```
/**
 * Enqueue audiosynth.
 */
function audiosynth_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'audiosynth', get_theme_file_uri( '/js/audiosynth.js' ), array(), filemtime( get_theme_file_path( '/js/audiosynth.js' ) ), false );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'audiosynth.view', get_theme_file_uri( '/js/audiosynth.view.js' ), array(), filemtime( get_theme_file_path( '/js/audiosynth.view.js' ) ), false );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'audiosynth.view.fire', get_theme_file_uri( '/js/audiosynth.view.fire.js' ), array(), filemtime( get_theme_file_path( '/js/audiosynth.view.fire.js' ) ), true );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'audiosynth_scripts' );
```

Now, open the `style.css` file inside **mytheme** and add the following at the very end of it :

```
.key {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 12px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(32, 32, 32, 0.2);
    border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 1px rgba(32, 32, 32, 0.2);
    -webkit-transition: margin 0.05s ease, background-color 0.05s ease, box-shadow 0.05s ease;
}

.key:hover {
    background-color: rgb(255, 192, 32);
}

.key .label {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}

.black {
    background-color: rgb(32, 32, 32);
    color: #ffffff;
    z-index: 1;
    text-shadow: 0px -1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.white {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: rgb(32, 32, 32);
    z-index: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(32, 32, 32, 0.5);
}

.keyboard-options {
    margin: 30px auto;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 200;
    padding: 10px;
}

.keyboard-holder {
    margin: 30px auto;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
}
```

Now, you should add the following code, lets say at the very end of the `header.php` file that is inside **mytheme**.
DO NOT PUT THIS CODE INSIDE A `<?php ?>` tag, this is `HTML` :

```
<select ID="sound">
    <option value="0" selected>Keyboard</option>
    <option value="1">Organ</option>
    <option value="2">Acoustic Guitar</option>
    <option value="3">EDM, bro!</option>
</select>
<div ID="keyboard" class="keyboard-holder"></div>
<div class="keyboard-options">
    Range [C<span ID="OCTAVE_LOWER">3</span>-B<span ID="OCTAVE_UPPER">5</span>]
    <input type="button" ID="-_OCTAVE" value="-" />
    <input type="button" ID="+_OCTAVE" value="+" /><br />
    <i>(Use left/right arrows to adjust with keyboard)</i>
</div>
```

NOW, go to your site, refresh the page and tada !!!

SYA :)

Comment: I got "The site is experiencing technical difficulties."

Comment: Are you putting the `audiosynth.js` file in a `js` folder at the same level as `style.css` ???

Comment: I fixed that, I add an instance of function chicken_wings_scripts() { before, so I just changed that

Comment: The Javascript code doesn't have any CSS code, it's only a Js file, look here http://keithwhor.github.io/audiosynth/

Comment: I'm not saying that it have a `css` file ! At the root of your theme you have a `style.css` file. You have to create a `js` folder (if you don't have one) at the root of your theme, at the same level as `style.css` :) Inside this `js` folder, put the downloaded `audiosynth.js`

Comment: That exactly what I did http://prntscr.com/odu49n , my challenge is to call the piano to be visible on my page

Comment: See the **EDIT** part and follow it :) Don't forget to accept the answer after it works for you :)

Comment: Thanks, already fixed it, then I saw your edit, you are a good dude!